# Mp3 player with progressBar, with multiple Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3

What are the best approach to create a mp3 player, with progress bar update.  BUT, I have to switch between 2 activity, and the mp3 need to continue play\update progress bar  on one of the 2 activity.

On iOS, i can use "singleton" and Notification(or delegate).  On Android, i've heard about "services", but not sure. :)

Comment: Yup... you need to implement a service that handles the player state and the ongoing notification. Check google, there is dozens of good examples.

Comment: Yes, some examples, but no library like cocoacontrols, etc. :(